# Animation css3 blinking stars

Tags: css

Please help with the following code :-

Html:-

```
<figure class="star">
<figure class="star-top"></figure>
<figure class="star-bottom"></figure>
</figure>
```

Js:-

```
var limit=100, // Max number of starts
  body=document.body;
loop={
//initilizeing
start:function(){
    for (var i=0; i <= limit; i++) {
        var star=this.newStar();
        star.style.top=this.rand()*100+"%";
        star.style.left=this.rand()*100+"%";
        star.style.webkitAnimationDelay=this.rand()+"s";
        star.style.mozAnimationDelay=this.rand()+"s";
        body.appendChild(star);
    };
},
//to get random number
rand:function(){
    return Math.random();
},
//createing html dom for star
newStar:function(){
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.innerHTML = '<figure class="star"><figure class="star-top"></figure>
          <figure class="star-bottom"></figure></figure>';
    return d.firstChild;
},
  };
  loop.start();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H29j7/

The background and star animation is covering the entire body element. I want to define a div element and restrict the background and star animation within that div so that I can define a custom height for it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create a container for the stars:

```
<div id="container">
<figure class="star">
  <figure class="star-top"></figure>
  <figure class="star-bottom"></figure>
 </figure>
</div>
```

Now refer to the container instead of the `body` in your script:

```
var container=document.getElementById('container');
```

And then style it up:

```
#container{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: #212121;
    position:relative;
}
```

ref: http://jsfiddle.net/H29j7/6/